# How can you prove this equality?

Tags: integration, proof-writing, logarithms

I am trying to figure out the following equality, but cannot seem to get anywhere. I tried integrating by parts, but that blew up when I set *u = (log x)^n* and tried to take log (0). I also tried differentiating the right side but got stuck when I did not know the derivative of $n!$

How can we prove that the following is true:

$$
\int_0^1 x^a(\log x)^n \,dx= \frac{(-1)^n(n!)}{(a+1)^{n+1}}
$$

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: These kind of things usually succumb to integration by parts and then induction.

Comment: (1) $\log x\to -\infty$ as $x\to 0$, anyway, so this was an improper integral in the first place, so you should expect that sort of behavior; (2) $n!$ is a constant (if we're differentiating with respect to $x$), so its derivative is zero; (3) Since we're dealing with a definite integral, the whole right side is a constant, so we can't be taking a derivative anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Applying integration by parts:

$$
\int_0^1 x^a(log x)^ndx = \lim_{b\to 0^+}\left[(\log(x))^{n}\frac{1}{a+1}x^{a+1}\Big|_{b}^1\right]-\frac{n}{a+1}\int_0^1 x^{a}(\log x)^{n-1}dx
$$

Now if $a>-1$, you can show with L'Hopital's rule that

$$\lim_{b\to 0^+}\left[(\log(b))^{n}b^{a+1}\right] = 0$$

Hence

$$\int_0^1 x^a(log x)^ndx = -\frac{n}{a+1}\int_0^1 x^{a}(\log x)^{n-1}dx$$

See the inductive pattern now? Why you will have $n$ factors of $ (-1)$ when you're finished?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}x^{a}\ln^{n}\pars{x}\,\dd x
     = {\pars{-1}^{n}\,n! \over \pars{a + 1}^{n+1}}:\ {\large ?}}$

> With $\ds{a > -1}$:
>   \begin{align}
> \color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}x^{a}\ln^{n}\pars{x}\,\dd x}&=
> \lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald[n]{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}x^{a + \mu}\,\dd x
> =
> \lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald[n]{}{\mu}\pars{1 \over a + \mu + 1}
> =
> \partiald[n]{}{a}\pars{1 \over a + 1}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \partiald[n - 1]{}{a}\pars{-1 \over \pars{a + 1}^{2}}
> =
> \partiald[n - 2]{}{a}\pars{2 \over \pars{a + 1}^{3}}
> =
> \partiald[n - 3]{}{a}\pars{-3\times 2 \over \pars{a + 1}^{4}}
> \\[3mm]&=\cdots=
> \partiald[n - k]{}{a}\pars{\pars{-1}^{k}k! \over \pars{a + 1}^{k + 1}}
> =\cdots=\color{#00f}{\large{\pars{-1}^{n}\,n! \over \pars{a + 1}^{n + 1}}}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^a \log^n(x) = \dfrac{\partial^n}{\partial a^n} x^a$, so you just need to start with $\int_0^1 x^a\ dx$ and take some derivatives.   Of course you do need $a > -1$ for this to converge.